# Weird crash happening while clearing edittext

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-edittext

Crash is not happening everytime, its pretty random. I was able to notice it on a device while clearing text from prepopulated edittext.

Error Log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: offset(20) should be less than line limit(19)
   at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:353)
   at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:1213)
   at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:1190)
   at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:1160)
   at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:1149)
   at android.widget.Editor$ActionPinnedPopupWindow.computeLocalPosition(Editor.java:3315)
   at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:3619)
   at android.widget.Editor$ActionPinnedPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:3462)
   at android.widget.Editor$EmailAddPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:4986)
   at android.widget.Editor$1.run(Editor.java:1527)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7592)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Any help or suggestion are welcome, Thanks.

Comment: Add your code snippet to find the bug.

Comment: Put you code here, I guess you are getting some value by the position.

Comment: It is pretty random, I have edittext in 100s of places. Somewhere it crashes, somewhere it doesnt.